# Error C2079: 'CharCreateobject' uses undefined class 'CharacterCreation' + error C2228: left of '.CharacterRace' must have class/struct/union

Tags: c++

I am trying to build a dos mmorpg, and have already ran into a problem that might be very obvious, but I do not see it. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <ostream>
#define yes 1
using namespace std;     
class CharacterCreation;

class CharacterAttributes;

int main()
{

CharacterCreation CharCreateobject; 
CharCreateobject.CharacterRace(); 



} 

class CharacterCreation
{

public:
void CharacterRace()
{


    int Race;
    char YesOrNo;
    cout << "Are you sure you would like to make a character? " << endl;
    cin >> YesOrNo;

    cout << "Please enter the number of the race you would like to be " << endl;
    cout << "1. Human" << endl << "2. Elf" << endl << "3. Giant" << endl << "4. Griffon" << endl << "5. Dwarf" << endl << "6. Orc" << endl;
    cin >> Race;
    CharacterAttributes CharAttributObject;
    switch (Race)
    {

    case 1:
        cout << "You are a Human." << endl;

        CharAttributObject.CharHuman();
        break;
    case 2:
        cout << "You are an Elf." << endl;

    case 3:
        cout << "You are a Giant." << endl;

    case 4:
        cout << "You are a Griffon." << endl;

    case 5:
        cout << "You are a Dwarf." << endl;

    case 6:
        cout << "You are an Orc." << endl;

    }



}



};

class CharacterAttributes
{

public:
void CharHuman()
{

    cout << "TEST!" << endl;

}

};
```

I really don't know what I have done, but I suspect that the errors are wrong. 
If you could help, please do tell me as it would be appreciated!:) 
Once again, here is my error:

```
Error C2079: 'CharCreateobject' uses undefined class 'CharacterCreation'
error C2228: left of '.CharacterRace' must have class/struct/union
```

I also have two of each of these errors. 
It looks like this with all errors:

```
Error C2079: 'CharCreateobject' uses undefined class 'CharacterCreation'     

error C2228: left of '.CharacterRace' must have class/struct/union  

Error   3   error C2079: 'CharAttributObject' uses undefined class 'CharacterAttributes'    

Error   4   error C2228: left of '.CharHuman' must have class/struct/union
```

Comment: You need to define your class before creating instances of it.

Comment: Are you talking about prototyping it? If so, I already have that.

Comment: You don't have to prototype it. you have to define it. And that is exactly your error: `'CharCreateobject' uses undefined class 'CharacterCreation'`

Comment: "CharacterCreation" is defined..? It holds "CharacterRace()" in it

Comment: At the point where you use it (`CharacterCreation CharCreateobject;`), it is not defined yet.

Comment: Is it not defined by the prototype?

Comment: No (and technically that's not a prototype, it's a class declaration). To create objects of a class, the compiler has to know its size and members, so it must have seen the full definition.

Comment: Ahhh. I thought the prototype (or class decleration) automatically told the compiler about the classes inside the class. I'm guessing all I have to do is add "void CharacterRace()" as a prototype, right? :D I take that back, it didn't work...Could I have a link to be told what to do?

Comment: I don't think C++ even has the concept of a prototype. In C, a "prototype" is the typed parameter list between `(` and `)` in a function declaration. E.g. `void foo();` (declaration without prototype) and `void bar(void);` (declaration with prototype `void`)

Comment: You wouldn't mind telling me what to do to fix this, would you?

Comment: Could I please have help fixing this?

Comment: You point out my flaw, but you don't help me fix it...wtf?

Comment: Dude, what's unclear? What part do you need help with?

Comment: How do you fix it? Maybe I'm just being dumb, but it seems like you've pointed out what's wrong but you have told me what to put in..?

Comment: The very first comment: *You need to define your class before creating instances of it.*

Comment: Yeah, that was the pointing out part, but what do I put in? I've tried a few things...but I really don't know.

Comment: I really need a reply...

Comment: Do you even have an answer or do you just pretend to know what you're doing?

Comment: I don't think you even know what you're talking about. You haven't replied in 21 hours and yet you tell me what's wrong, but not how to fix it....WTF?!

Comment: omfg, am I getting a reply? Pointing me at someone else's question doesn't help me!